# Как получить строки без None (убрать None, но сами строки сохранить)?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Дело в том чтобы я использовал бы `IS NOT NULL` но тут другая ситуация. Вот пример таблицы:

```
   column1      column2     col3  col4  col5    column6     col7  col8

('494783432', '4324206976', None, None, None, None, '4440898453', None)

('123487746', '1650205433', None, None, None, '1230898345', None, None)

('444487746', '1650202422', None, None, None, '5540898645', None, None)

('675487746', '1234206714', None, '5430898756', None, None, None, None)

('899887746', '2312206620', None, None, None, None, None, '4230898234')

('112287746', '1650212312', '7560898645', None, None, None, None, None)
```

Чтобы получить эти строки я использовал `SELECT`, но мне нужно получить эти данные без лишних `None`. В пайтоне они отображаются как `None` а в `sqlite3` - `NULL`

Я хочу получить такой результат на примере первой строки:

```
('494783432', '4324206976', '4440898453')
```

Comment: None в Python является эквивалентом null в sql. Если пишете запрос в sql используйте null

Comment: то-есть как мне оформить select?

Comment: Уточните, что вы хотите - чтобы эти строки, которые вы привели в виде примера, вообще не выбирались из базы? А в чём проблема - что много колонок, где может быть `NULL` и вы не хотите их все перечислять через `AND` в `WHERE` части `SELECT` или в чём? `WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL AND col4 IS NOT NULL AND...`

Comment: Наоборот всё хорошо! Я просто хочу получить результат ('494783432', '4324206976',  '4440898453') на примере первой строки

Comment: то-есть без None

Comment: то-есть мне надо каждую колонку перечислять чтобы вывести без NULL?

Comment: А у вас чистый питон, не `Pandas` какой, просто кортежи получаете? Может быть проще и правда на стороне питона будет сделать, щас подумаю

Comment: Не. То что вы хотите проще сделать на питоне просто отфильтровав кортеж каждой записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На стороне питона это сделать довольно просто с помощью `filter`:

```py
lst = [
('494783432', '4324206976', None, None, None, None, '4440898453', None),
('123487746', '1650205433', None, None, None, '1230898345', None, None),
('444487746', '1650202422', None, None, None, '5540898645', None, None),
('675487746', '1234206714', None, '5430898756', None, None, None, None),
('899887746', '2312206620', None, None, None, None, None, '4230898234'),
('112287746', '1650212312', '7560898645', None, None, None, None, None),
]

lst_ = [tuple(filter(None, item)) for item in lst]
print(*lst_, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
('494783432', '4324206976', '4440898453')
('123487746', '1650205433', '1230898345')
('444487746', '1650202422', '5540898645')
('675487746', '1234206714', '5430898756')
('899887746', '2312206620', '4230898234')
('112287746', '1650212312', '7560898645')
```

Comment: Спасибо, то нужно было, а если бы через IS NOT NULL то оно бы показало пустой результат, то-есть не было бы результата совсем

Comment: @Kowl Просто сначала не совсем понятно было, что вы хотите. Всегда нужно приводить примеры: 1) вот что у меня есть 2) вот что я хочу из этого получить 3) вот что у меня получается (если у вас есть своё решение и оно не работает)

Comment: Понял спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Kowl Я добавил ваш комментарий с ожидаемым результатом в текст вопроса, теперь вопрос будет более понятным тем, кто его будет в будущем читать. Может пригодится кому )